# c++ Specializing class behavior for same types

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have to write a class that acts on data that can take two values. However, there are two possibilities for what this data can be, it can either be 0/1-valued (i.e. booly), or -1/+1-valued (i.e. spinny).

The class behavior, depending on whether it encounters booly input or spinny input, will be markedly different (i.e., it will not be sufficient to merely convert using y = 1 - 2x.), because the equations have different forms.

I was wondering what the least redundant and most flexible way to implement this would be.

Should I

1. Just put both cases in each method and use a flag member variable to choose the right case
2. Write two entirely separate classes for each case
3. Use template specialization or overloading somehow

   I would prefer this, but I don't know how it could work. It would be fine if I was dealing with, for example, an 'int' case and a 'float' case, but -1/+1 and 0/1 are both just ints, so I can't differentiate them by type... unless maybe I could define some kind of fundamental 'spinny' type that could only take the values -1/+1, but I don't know how to do that either.
4. Do something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably define a spinny type (and use `bool` for the other one). The easiest way is to use a strongly typed enum:

```
enum class Spin : int {
    UP = +1,
    DOWN = -1,
};
```

This ensures that you can't accidentally treat a booly value as a spinny one or *vice versa.* As a bonus, it also solves your problem (with overloading or template specialization).

Note that it's still possible to get an "invalid" spin value by explicitly `static_cast`ing from an `int` other than +1 or -1. Just don't do that, and you'll be golden.